# Not Able to Login to Application - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2019

I am unable to login to my application in my local after upgrading the SQL Server 2019 - I'm getting this error:

[image: Login ErrorMessage]

I have uninstalled older SQL Server versions, and installed SQL Server 2019. And earlier the server name was `(local)`, but the new server name is `<MyMachineName>\MSSQLSERVER1`.

Troubleshooting steps:

1. I am able to connect to SQL Server (using SSMS) using `MSSQLSERVER1`
2. All the SQL Server related services are running fine. Please refer to this screenshot: [Currently active Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijvaA.png)
3. I have also tried connecting to SQL Server using port, but it's not connecting.

[Currently running ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c66mB.png)

4. And TCP/IP is enabled => Sql Server Configuration Manager -> Sql Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER -> TCP/IP

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjft2.png)

According to new server name, I have changed my connection string in the config file :

```
<add key="ConnectionString" 
     value="server=<MyMachineName>\MSSQLSERVER1;database=XXXX;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;">
</add>
```

Could you please help me, what is going wrong here.

Comment: In the message it tells you that it wants to use named pipes yet named pipes are disabled in the configuration manager. Enable named pipes or find a way to force it to use TCP.

Comment: I have also tried enabling the Names Pipes, I still seeing same error message

Comment: So are you running this on the same machine as SQL Server or a remote workstation? If the latter, have you opened the firewall correctly (`sqlservr.exe` any port and SQL Browser on 1434)? What is the actual instance name?

Comment: The connection string has to be the same as the Login Window of SSMS.   A server has a machine name and instance which you will see in SSMS login window.

Comment: If possible restart the SQL Server after enabling the Named Pipes. There are also two different Client Configuration tool for SQL Server, 32bit and 64bit. If you made changes on 64 bit but your application is 32bit then it won't work. See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5133/different-ways-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-sqlcmd/ 
You can also try to connect using `sqlcmd` command line tool by specifying the connection method.

Comment: Thank you all for the response, I am using connection string server name as same as SSMS login i.e "<MyMachineName>\MSSQLSERVER1" and this is my SQL server instance name as well. I have also restarted my SQL Server Services, still no luck. And also SQL server and my application both are running on my same machine (Local)

Comment: This issue started after installing SQL server 2019 , I was good before that and my earlier the server name was (local), but the new server name is <MyMachineName>\MSSQLSERVER1